# Prevent NotesDocument looking for redundant server on open

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a moderately old app that has been moved to a new server and the old server has been decommissioned.

Every programmatic reference to the old server has been re-pointed to the new server.  When users open any document in the db, I can see the silent trying to reference the old server, before giving up and going to the new server.

I've tried debugging to see if I can track down code that may be doing this, but it happens before the debugger kicks in.  I thought it may be the workspace or bookmarks, but having replaced these with brand new ones, I still get the same results.

Any ideas of what else I could check?

EDIT:

Have found a few @DbColumns in computed fields using a replicaID to reference the database.  This database appears on the new server too.

Answer (score 0):

If `@DbColumn` and `@DbLookup` formulas use replica ids, the Notes client remembers what server the referenced database was last opened from, and keeps trying to use that server.
The last-used server should be whatever appears as the current server in the workspace for each related database. If *none* of the related databases show the old server in the workspace, then I don't know what's going on.

Assuming one or more related databases still show the old server in the workspace, the normal solution is to manually open every referenced database from the new server on the affected clients, but there are other solutions.

One option to automate fixing these references is to have some LotusScript that runs when users open the main database, using `NotesDatabase.OpenByReplicaID` to find related databases on the correct server, and `NotesUIWorkspace.AddDatabase` to set the workspace icons to that server. This kind of code can take several seconds, so I recommend to design a way of controlling it by configuration.

Another option is a commercial third-party tool like Panagenda MarvelClient, but I haven't personally used that tool or anything similar, and can't comment on the long-term value.
(Disclaimer: My employer is a Panagenda partner.)

Comment: Had thought of this as I use the AddDatabase/OpenByReplicID code elsewhere.  The problem still occurs when the workspace has been completely destroyed and recreated.